# How to split Test and Train data such that there is garenteed at least one of each Class in each

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have some fairly unbalanced data I am trying to classify.
However, it is classifying fairly well.

To evaluate exactly how well, I must split the data into training and test subsets.

Right now I am doing that by the very simple measure of:

```
import numpy as np
corpus = pandas.DataFrame(..., columns=["data","label"]) # My data, simplified
train_index = np.random.rand(len(corpus))>0.2
training_data = corpus[train_index]
test_data = corpus[np.logical_not(train_index)]
```

This is nice and simple, but some of the classes occur very very rarely:
about 15 occur less than 100 times each in the corpus of over 50,000 cases, and two of them each occur only once.

I would like to partition my data corpus into test and training subsets such that:

- If a class occurs less than twice, it is excluded from both
- each class occurs at least once, in test and in training
- The split into test and training is otherwise random

I can throw together something to do this,
(likely the simplest way is to remove things with less than 2 occurances) and then just resample til the spit has both on each side), but I wonder if there is a clean method that already exists.

I don't think that [sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split) will do for this, but that it exists suggests that sklearn might have this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following meets your 3 conditions for partitioning the data into test and training:

```
#get rid of items with fewer than 2 occurrences.
corpus=corpus[corpus.groupby('label').label.transform(len)>1]

from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedShuffleSplit
sss=StratifiedShuffleSplit(corpus['label'].tolist(), 1, test_size=0.5, random_state=None)

train_index, test_index =list(*sss)
training_data=corpus.iloc[train_index]
test_data=corpus.iloc[test_index]
```

I've tested the code above by using the following fictitious dataframe:

```
#create random data with labels 0 to 39, then add 2 label case and one label case.     
corpus=pd.DataFrame({'data':np.random.randn(49998),'label':np.random.randint(40,size=49998)})
corpus.loc[49998]=[random.random(),40]
corpus.loc[49999]=[random.random(),40]
corpus.loc[50000]=[random.random(),41]
```

Which produces the following output when testing the code:

```
test_data[test_data['label']==40]
Out[110]: 
           data  label
49999  0.231547     40

training_data[training_data['label']==40]
Out[111]: 
           data  label
49998  0.253789     40

test_data[test_data['label']==41]
Out[112]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [data, label]
Index: []

training_data[training_data['label']==41]
Out[113]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [data, label]
Index: []
```

Comment: Instead of the forloop shouldn't: it be `train_indexes, test_indexes = list(*splitter);
train_data = common_corpus.iloc[train_indexes,:];
test_data = common_corpus.iloc[test_indexes,:]`

Comment: You're right @Oxinabox that is a cleaner way to do it.  The loop is mostly useful for `n_iter` values in `StratifiedShuffleSplit()` that are >1 if you're doing multiple splits on the data.  I'll modify the answer using your suggested replacement.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `iloc` instead of `loc` so it works right if the index is not a simple range?

Comment: `iloc` is the better answer and I've modified the answer to reflect this.  Thanks.